# 'str' object is not callable: Python Outlook email

Tags: python, email, outlook

```
shopping_mail = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'Balenciaga' in message.Subject()] 
for message in shopping_mail: 
message.Move(Shopping)
```

Output:

```
----> 2 shopping_mail = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'Balenciaga' in message.Subject()]
      3 for message in shopping_mail:
      4     message.Move(Shopping)
      5 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is the code I have used. Trying to move emails with this phrase to an existing folder. This is all done in Outlook.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you calling a string? Did you mean: `if 'Balenciaga' in message.Subject`?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to python. What would be the correct way to code this?

Comment: You have an error on line 2. To fix the error I think you should have: `shopping_mail = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'Balenciaga' in message.Subject]`

Comment: ahh okay it's fixed. Thank you. what exactly does the ( ) do then when i applied it  to the code?

Comment: The `()` is the instruction in lots of programming languages to call a function. Your code only requires referencing the string attribute `Subject`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python expert, but you may try to remove parenthesis from the `Subject` property name:

```
shopping_mail = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'Balenciaga' in message.Subject()]
```

From the Outlook object model standpoint I'd recommend using the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the `Items` class instead. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)